# Background image not sizing or displaying in Ipad landscape

Tags: html, css, image, ipad, background

I've been endlessly searching the web for an answer to this and have come across numerous solutions that haven't seemed to work for me. I am implementing a responsive web design that has a background image that needs to cover the screen and resize so that the width is always 100% and does not get cut off. It is working on desktop and mobile fine but I am having problems with Ipad when it is landscape. It was highly zoomed in to the top corner of the image so that you could only see around 5% of the image. I then took out the background positioning animation and it now does not show the image at all.

We are using one image for screens bigger than 768px and one for smaller devices below. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<section id="fh5co-home" data-section="home" class="background ">
    <div class="container bg-image">
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.background {
background-image: url(../images/desk.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-o-background-size: contain;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
.bg-image {
    background-image: url(../images/three.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-size:cover;         
}
}
```

I have tried using contain and cover, as well as setting the background attachment to fixed. I've also tried removing the "no repeat".

Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated. I'm fairly new to implementing and its been driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you define a viewport in the <head>? Like this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: Hi, I did not. However I have managed to fix the problem. There was a background fixed coming from another generated element and also the image was above 1024px width, so by reducing the image size for the Ipad and removing the fixed background it now works!